# Write a NodeJS class that transmits periodic information to a long running python program

Tags: python, node.js

I am going to write a nodeJS class that transmits periodic information to a long running python program.

Should use nodeJS "child_process" class.
Should pass json style data to python program. (eg {x:1, y:0})
Python to keep a local instance of x & y.
Python to respond with the incremented value of x & y.
        stdin stdout
    eg: {x:1, y:0}  => {x:1, y:0}
        {x:1, y:0}  => {x:2, y:0}
        {x:0, y:1}  => {x:2, y:1}
        {x:-1,y:0}  => {x:1, y:1}

Latency between nodeJS & Python to be < 5ms average.
Python program to be implemented as a long running process and not spawned again every time nodeJS calls the program.
Any advice?

Comment: Why can't you use Python for this process?

Comment: I have to integrate this class in my nodejs backend.